# Creating java object with enum in constructor from html form

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, enums

I Have java class like this:

```
public class Action{

private String title;
private String description;

private ActionState actionState;

public Action(){};
public Action(String title, String description, ActionState actionState)
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.actionState = actionState;
}




public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public ActionState getActionState() {
    return actionState;
}
```

}

and controllers:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new/addAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addAction(@RequestBody Action action){
    actionService.add(action);
}

   @RequestMapping(value = "/new/actionStates", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> returnActionsStates(){
     return actionService.enumToStringList(ActionState.class);
}
```

first is responsible for writing object to DB, second sends my ENUMS names to angular controller

enum class looks like this:

```
public enum ActionState {

CREATED,
OPENED,
CLOSED
```

}

here is angular controller

```
app.controller('actionController',function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addAction = function(action){
        $scope.action = {};
            $http.post('actions/new/addAction', action).success(function(){
                $scope.action.title='';
                $scope.action.description='';
            })
}

$scope.getActionStates = function() {
    $http.get('actions/new/actionStates').success(function(actionTypesState){
        $scope.states = actionTypesState;
    })
}
```

and finally html form

```
<b>Ttitle</b><input type="text" data-ng-model="action.title">
<br>
<b>Description</b><input type="text" data-ng-model="action.description">

<div data-ng-init="getActionStates()">
<b>Action State</b> <select id="actionState">
<option value="">-- choose--</option>
<option data-ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state}}">{{state}}</option>
</select><br>
</div>
<br>
<button data-ng-click="addAction(action)">submit</button>
```

Its works for title and description. I mean `Action` object in my `addAction` controller have its title value equal with one i typed in html form, its same for description.

Question is: How to make it works this same way with my `enum` value?

I know I can just send `String` with enum name and then create it in controller with `valueOf` method. But I want to this whole object to be created automagically :).

I would be gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wonder, Spring automatically convert JSON to ENUM.
Problem here was html code, which didn't send JSON at all.
With following code it works

```
<div data-ng-init="getActionStates()">
    <b>Action State</b> <select data-ng-model="action.actionState" data-ng-options="actionState for (id, actionState) in states">
    <option value="">{{neutralActionState}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```